# Is there a way to access the haptic feedback via WatchKit?

Tags: ios, watchkit

I plan to create an Apple Watch app.  Is there a way to access the haptic feedback via WatchKit?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No there isn't.  The following is from this post https://devforums.apple.com/thread/254540?tstart=15.

> There is no access to these hardware features at this time, though
>   there is presentation of a text input controller via
>   WKInterfaceController, which will involve the microphone. Past that, I
>   have no information concerning forthcoming releases.

Comment: Note that this is true only for the original version of WatchKit. See other answers for API features of subsequent versions.

Answer (score 19):

Yes. As of watchOS 2.0, you can give haptic feedback with [the `play()` method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkinterfacedevice/1628128-play) method like this:

```
WKInterfaceDevice.currentDevice().play(.success)
```

Comment: There's also a full guide [here](http://www.sneakycrab.com/blog/2015/6/22/haptic-feedback-with-the-taptic-engine-in-watchkit-and-watchos-2-wkinterfacedevice-and-wkhaptic) which goes through the different `WKHapticType` options and what they all mean.

Comment: I love when Apple creates two different APIs, one to play haptics on iOS and another for the watch.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

For now, the only way to give haptic feedback is by showing a notification.