# iOS long vibration

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I have an application that can detect accidents, it is really important for us to alert users using vibration and alert sound if an accident is detected.

My questions are:

- Is it possible to add long vibration in application by using custom sounds or something that apple might be ok with?
- If I use private apis, is it possible to convince apple to approve my app considering that the use case is really critical?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vibrate for a long time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22836211/vibrate-for-a-long-time)

Answer (score 1):

Two questions here, really.

**1st one**: haptic feedback / control vibration on iOS / custom iOS patterns

No, it can't be done, [even in the new Apple Watch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27050919/is-there-a-way-to-access-the-haptic-feedback-via-watchkit) without Jailbreaking your phone. You can have a look at this [keyboard mod](https://code.google.com/p/zataangstuff/source/browse/trunk/HapticKeyboard/Classes/HapticKeyboard.m?r=93) (needs Jailbreak). [Here you have some code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265761/how-do-you-make-the-iphone-vibrate-for-arbitrary-durations?lq=1) but it needs Jailbreaking your phone.

If you need to alert your users I recommend just playing the default vibration inside a while. Sleep the current thread for 1 sec, then vibrate again until some boolean flag changes. Objective-C Pseudocode:

```
while (!endVibrationAlert) {
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1];
}


// when user touches some button to dismiss alert
self.endVibrationAlert = true;
```

**2nd one**: never ever try to bypass Apple's reviewing system. Abide by the rules. For your 1st version, maybe it passes. Then, in the next update your App can get rejected.

Comment: I read a lot of blogs about controlling or prolonging vibration and some guys also discouraged looping AudioServicesPlaySystemSound as apple has rejected apps in past for this reason (ref. http://stackoverflow.com/a/22836763/844295)