# How to vibrate iphone by pattern when push received?

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, iphone-vibrate

I want to vibrate device when i received the push notification.

push notification contains value of vibration like below:

`{ 0, 1000, 2000, 3000, 2000 }`

How can i vibrate iPhone using above pattern in objective-c ?

Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, It's not possible without Jailbreakin. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29727401/ios-long-vibration